# How to convert string date in util.date format?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a string date into util.Date format and i have tried this method as follows

```
String startingDate="25 Mar 2016";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Date date=sdf.parse(startingDate);
```

I wanted the date output to be "Fri Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2016" but i am getting "Thu Mar 24 18:30:00 UTC 2016" which is not correct because i am getting different TIMEZONE and i want "IST" Timezone. Please help ! Thanx in advance

Comment: If you are converting it to `Date` object then you'll have time also. Why you are converting the String to Date when you want the String in the first place?

Comment: No matter if i get time but i need that in IST format the output is in UTC format and i dont need that. And i want that in date because i want to use date.getTime() method available in date.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you want the console to print the Date in `IST` format instead of `UTC`. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already converted the `TimeZone` to `IST` by setting the `TimeZone` Property on the `SimpleDateFormat` and then parsing your input String using it.

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the console to print the Date in `IST` and not in `UTC` or `GMT`. For this you just need to change the default `TimeZone` to `IST` by doing:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String startingDate = "25 Mar 2016";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(startingDate));
}
```

Output:

```
Fri Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

Comment: @Rahul Your Welcome! Request you to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted the date output to be "25 Mar 2016"..

By default when you print `Date` instance `toString` method of `Date` class will be called and it will print the data of Date in `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format and so that you are getting `Thu Mar 24 18:30:00 UTC 2016`.

Currently, if you already have `Date` in `String` you don't need to format date you can simply use that `String`. You can also use `SimpleDateFormat#format(String dateString)` method to format the `Date` according to the specific pattern, here `dd MMM yyyy` and so format method will return you the formatted `String` of `Date` instance.

*NOTE :* Parsing the `Date` does not format the value of `Date` object. `SimpleDateFormat#parse` will convert the `String` of `dd MMM yyyy` to `Date` instance while `SimpleDateFormat#format` will return the `String` from `Date` in `dd MMM yyyy` format.

[`SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) says,

> The TimeZone set by this method may be overwritten as a result of a
>   call to the parse method.

Moreover, you can not set `TimeZone` on `Date` Object you use `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));` method before printing the `Date` which is already suggested by `user2004685`.

Comment: But why to convert the String to Date in the first place if the required output is String itself?

Comment: No problem if i get Time.. but i need that in IST format and the output is in UTC format because of which my date is "24th March" instead of "25th March"

Comment: @Rahul How are you getting output as `Thu Mar 24 18:30:00 UTC 2016` ? By printing `Date` on console ?

Comment: Nopes. I have used Logger and checked values in log of my app(On Server).

Comment: Thanx for answering and explaining @TAsk.

Answer (score 2):

The Question and other Answers are using outmoded classes.

## Avoid old date-time classes

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, and such bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later. Backports available for Java 6 & 7 and Android.

These new classes are a *vast* improvement over the old date-time classes. Search Stack Overflow for more discussions and examples.

For date-only values with no time-of-day, use the `LocalDate` class.

Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for the human language to interpret the name-of-month. If omitted the JVM’s current default `Locale` is implicitly applied. Better to specify explicitly the desired/expected Locale. For example, `Locale.US` or `Locale.ENGLISH` or `new Locale( "en" , "IN" )`, whatever is appropriate to your incoming data.

```
String input = "25 Mar 2016";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM yyyy" );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );  // Specify the language to interpret name-of-month.
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

To get a date-time with the first moment of the day, specify a time zone to create a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // Or "Europe/Paris", "America/Montreal", and such.
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Never assume the day starts at the time `00:00:00.0`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means the day may begin at another time. Let java.time handle such details for you by calling `atStartOfDay`.

Comment: Thanx for answering will try and use this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it here:

```
String startingDate="25 Mar 2016";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
System.out.println("Date: " + dateFormat.parse(startingDate));
```

Comment: Thanx for answering but i got the answer from user2004685